# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/axis2/transport/SimpleAxis2Server (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0

Tags: solaris, apache-axis

I'm having problem deploying Axis2 v1.5.3 on my 64 bit Solaris 9 OS, I wonder what should I do in order to successfully run this Axis2 instance with JDK 6 ?

In this OS there are multiple Java JDK version installed but I have already set the env. var to point to the 1.6 binary.

Suddenly I realize that I can always open up the **setenv.sh** file and then hard code it manually for safer option,

```
export AXIS2_HOME="/opt/local/sys/axis2-1.5.3"
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java1.6/bin/java"
export AXIS2_CLASSPATH="$AXIS2_CLASSPATH"
```

Here's the history log:

```
npapsg# uname -a
SunOS npapsg.domain.com 5.9 Generic_117171-17 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-280R

npapsg# pwd
/opt/local/sys/axis2-1.5.3/bin

npapsg# ls
axis2.bat        axis2server.sh   setenv.sh
axis2.sh         java2wsdl.bat    wsdl2java.bat
axis2server.bat  java2wsdl.sh     wsdl2java.sh

npapsg# env
TERM=xterm
HOME=/
SHELL=/bin/zsh
USER=root
LOGNAME=root
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0/bin:/usr/ucb:/bin:/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/SUNWspro-4.0.1/bin:/usr/ucb:/etc:/usr/ccs/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/etc:/opt/local/licenses:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/etc::/usr/cssc/bin::/opt/gnu/bin:/usr/gnu/bin:::/opt/X11R5/bin:/usr/local/X11/R5/bin:/home/products/openwin-3.2/bin:/home/products/openwin-3.2/demo::/opt/SUNWmotif/bin:/opt/java/bin:::/opt/local/cap/bin:/home/products/ddts/sol2x_bin:::.:/usr/openwin/bin
PWD=/opt/local/sys/axis2-1.5.3/bin
SHLVL=1
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0
HISTSIZE=1000
_=/usr/bin/env

npapsg# ./setenv.sh
 Using AXIS2_HOME:   /opt/local/sys/axis2-1.5.3
 Using JAVA_HOME:       /usr/java1.6/bin/java

npapsg# ./axis2server.sh
 Using AXIS2_HOME:   /opt/local/sys/axis2-1.5.3
 Using JAVA_HOME:       /usr/java1.6/bin/java
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/axis2/transport/SimpleAxis2Server (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)**
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:539)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:123)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:55)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:187)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:289)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:274)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:235)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:302)

npapsg#  /usr/java1.6/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0_06"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_06-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 10.0-b22, mixed mode)
```

Comment: when i type whereis and java -version it shows the old Java 1.4.2 path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this bit inside `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` for the user that is going to run this.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java1.6
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Restart the console session and make sure you get java 6 version when you run `java -showversion` command

Comment: how to restart the console session man ? do i just close my Putty and then reconnect again ?

Comment: thanks man, your suggestion really works :-) export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java1.6/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH